# Why cannot access CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firebug

I cannot affect a certain CSS class called 'sidebar.' I can affect the other classes without any trouble. Sidebar is a container which contains visitor-guide and searchform.

The CSS paths are similar for all the elements. Yet using the same CSS selector path for sidebar does not work. The CSS path is correct, but the element will not accept CSS. In Firebug, sidebar does not get highlighted in blue as the others do.

The HTML structure is:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <aside class="visitor-guide">
       <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/guide.png" />
       <p>Some text!</p>
    </aside>     
    <aside class="searchform">
        <aside id="search-4" class="widget widget_search">
              Search site
              <?php get_search_form(); ?> 
        </aside>
    </aside>
</aside>
```

Comment: can you show us your css as well? or better create a jsFiddle with the problem?

Comment: ".sidebar" should work (http://jsfiddle.net/5w2DU/).

Comment: how you call this css file in template?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to target the sidebar using `.sidebar` selector.

Example:

```
.sidebar {background: #ccc;}
```